# Need help in mixing colors in python

Tags: python

This what I have

- When you mix Red and Blue, you get Purple
- When you mix Red and Yellow, you get Orange
- When you mix Blue and Yellow, you get Green
- When you mix any color with Black, you get Black
- When you mix any color with White, you get a lighter version of that color.

Example: Red mixed with white gives Light Red.

- When you mix two of the same colors, you get the same color.

Need help with the last 3 parts:

```
color1 = input("Please enter a color(red, blue, yellow, black or white:")
color2 = input("please enter a different color(red, blue, yellow, black or white):")
if(color1 == "red" and color2 == "blue") or (color1 == "blue" and color2 == "red"):
   print("The result is purple")
elif(color1 == "red" and color2 =="yellow") or (color1 =="yellow" and color2 =="red"):
   print("the result is orange")
elif(color1 == "blue" and color2 =="yellow") or (color1 =="yellow" and color2 =="blue"):
    print("the result is green")
elif(color1 =="red" or "blue" or "yellow" and color2 =="black") or (color1 =="black" and color2 =="red" or "blue" or "yellow"):
   print("the result is black")
elif(color1 =="red" or "blue" or "yellow" and color2 =="white") or (color1 =="white" and color2 =="red" or "blue" or "yellow"):
   print("the result is light")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do to improve the readability and reduce the amount of code here. It might be worth having a read and coming back with any more questions you might have.

Firstly:

```
color1 == "red" or "blue" or "yellow"
```

is not doing what you expect it to. If `color1` is not `"red"` then this will evaluate as `'blue'`, which is a value, so the whole expression evaluates to true, regardless of what the value of `color1` is - consider this, which prints the statement shown:

```
color1 = "flying monkeys"
color2 = "white"
if (color1 =="red" or "blue" or "yellow" and color2 =="white"):
  print("Wait - I didn't want flying monkeys!")
```

The long form of what I think you're trying to write is this, the print statement does not execute:

```
color1 = "flying monkeys"
color2 = "white"
if (color1 == "red" or color1 == "blue" or color1 == "yellow" and color2 =="white"):
  print("Wait - I didn't want flying monkeys!")
```

## Lists

Your code could be improved with the use of lists - these two statements are equivalent:

```
color1 == "red" or color1 == "blue" or color1 == "yellow" and color2 =="white"


color1 in ["red","blue","yellow"] and color2 == "white"
```

Likewise, if you just want to test if black or white are chosen, you can create a list using `color1` and `color2` and do:

```
elif "black" in [color1,color2]:
...
elif "white" in [color1,color2]:
...
```

For Light XXX, you want to find out the color that is not white if white is in the list. To do that, use a list comprehension, this says build a new list of colors from our list that are not white, that'll only return one colour so select [0] - the first element:

```
light_shade = [c for c in [color1,color2] if c != "white"][0]

print(f"the result is light {light_shade}")
```

Finally, you are doing a lot of repetition in the conditions. Consider using sets, which are special lists where the order does not matter. The following two lines are equivalent:

```
if(color1 == "red" and color2 == "blue") or (color1 == "blue" and color2 == "red"):

if set([color1,color2]) == set(["red","blue"])
```

The latter form will evaluate to true for both:

```
color1 = "red"
color2 = "blue"

color1 = "blue"
color2 = "red"
```